# Efficient way to store images to DB from PHP GD image object

Tags: php, gd

I need to generate and store a lot of small (1-10KB) PNG images (>10 millions) to the database.
The only thing I care is images/s throughput. For now I know two ways of storing GD image object to the database:

#### Use output buffer:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($image);
$imageData = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

#### Use temporary file (tmpfs/ramfs):

```
$tmpFilePath = '/dev/shm/file_000.png';
imagepng($image, $tmpFilePath);
$imageData = file_get_contents($thumbnail);
```

#### <strike>Update. There is a 3rd method: Use PHP memory stream:</strike>

```
// PHP streams are NOT supported
$tmpFilePath = 'php://memory';
imagepng($image, $tmpFilePath);
$imageData = file_get_contents($tmpFilePath);
```

My question is are there any other ways to write image to DB? Any pros/cons of each method.
Maybe it is worth to write a custom stream, which writes data to DB directly?

**Note**: Storing images to filesystem is NOT an option.

### Benchmark results:

[image: Generating and saving 10k PNG images]

Comment: writing a custom method that streams to the database would be really nice, but I'm not sure what database servers support blob-streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try letting `imagepng()` writing to a [memory stream](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) instead of a file.

```
$tmpFilePath = 'php://memory/file_000.png';

imagepng($image, $tmpFilePath);
$imageData = file_get_contents($tmpFilePath);
```

Although I'm not sure the `imagepng()` function can handle I/O streams, if it does, it could be a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other way: `imagepng()` doesn't have the option of returning the data stream (a design error in my eyes, but what are you going to do).

Which of the abovementioned ways is better for you, you should benchmark; writing a stream wrapper might be worth it, because it saves the step of writing the file.

Comment: I will prepare a benchmark a little bit later. For now I am focusing on possible choices.

Answer (score 0):

Writing image to temporary file would only increase disk I/O, so using memory buffer is a good choice. You can then upload them into DB with prepared statement's send_long_data function. (But you probably already know that.)

Comment: I am not sure about if I use send_long_data (it's worth another question). What do you mean by saying memory buffer?

Comment: I meant the `$imageData = ob_get_contents();` line, when you are loading image into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Both are unlikely to influence your total runtime since openreadclose'ing a cached file on linux these days takes about 20 microseconds. Generating and compressing the images is going to be the time-eater (you should optimize first the part that takes the most time). If you really want to save 1% on your total time, use the ob_() functions.

Anyway, if you want to store those in a database, examine your database connection library performance with BLOBs, some are pretty awful, others are fast.

Comment: In my case BLOB's are small, so there is a hope to achieve really nice performance :)

Comment: You are wrong about time-eater. 10k images are generated in 16s (on two Xenon 5650 cores). Generating and writing all images to HDD takes 187s although the reason might be imagepng method.

Comment: Saving 10.000 files will take less than a second (unless you use NTFS of course) ; however, PNG involves compression which takes time. Can you provide a few sample images ?

Comment: As you can see from the results, writing to memory 10k is 3x faster. Total time saving is a more than 1%.